# Facebook always changes Dutch word 'heeft' to 'heft'

Tags: facebook, autocorrect

Within FaceBook, on Windows 10, Microsoft Edge, inside a chat with another FaceBook user, it keeps changing the Dutch word 'heeft' (meaning 'has' from 'to have') into 'heft', which is also a Dutch word, but barely used.

In principle I like autocorrects, but in this case how can I write the word 'heeft', or how can I remove an autocorrect? Or otherwise, is it possible to switch off autocorrect completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before.  Type, backspace through the auto-correction, retype, do again if necessary, then add the new word to your dictionary. This works for me.

Comment: Backspace didn't work, but typing a space (so it changed to 'heft') and pressing undo (ctrl-Z) worked. Than I could use the 'add to dictionary'  option. Now it is part of the dictionary, it doesn't change it in future anymore. Thanks!